# Почему код продолжает работать после StopCoroutine()?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мигание реализовал через 2 кнопки: 1 темная кнопка, 2 светлая кнопка.
Первая `.SetActive(false)`, вторая `.SetActive(true)` и так чередуется...

После `StopCoroutine(myFunc(btn1, btn2))` останавливается мигание и снова продолжается.
Если передать название функции как строку `StopCoroutine("myFunc")`, то всё работает, но благодаря этому мне придется создавать еще функции: `myFunc2`, `myFunc3`... потому что кнопок больше 2-х, не хочется дублировать.

Как остановить мигание?
Как написать универсальную функцию для корутинов?

```
// class Btns
static public Btns S;
private IEnumerator _coroutine;

void Awake () {
 S = this;
}

public void startFI () {
  _coroutine = BlinkindRun (btn1, btn2);
// 1. пробовал _coroutine = StartCoroutine ( BlinkindRun (btn1, btn2) );
// 2. пробовал StartCoroutine ("_coroutine");
  StartCoroutine (_coroutine);
}

public void stopFI () {
 // 3. пробовал _coroutine = BlinkindRun (btn1, btn2);
 // 4. пробовал StopCoroutine ("_coroutine");
 // 5. пробовал StopCoroutine ("BlinkindRun");
  StopCoroutine (_coroutine);
}

private IEnumerator BlinkindRun (GameObject offGO, GameObject onGO) {
        while (true) {
            blinkBtn(offGO, onGO);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);

            blinkBtn(onGO, offGO);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
        }
    }

public void blinkBtn (GameObject offGO, GameObject onGO, bool blinkGO = false) {
        offGO.SetActive (false);
        onGO.SetActive (true);
    }


// class B
private void Awake () {
        UIButton1.onClick.AddListener (onStep1Touch);
        UIButton2.onClick.AddListener (onStep2Touch);
}

private void onStep1Touch () {
  Btns.S.startFI ();
}

private void onStep2Touch () {
  Btns.S.stopFI ();
}
```

Comment: Если корутина вызывается когда игрок шагнул и там коснулся чего-то, то скорее всего каждый кадр вызвалась корутина и выполнялись они поочередно

Comment: Насколько я знаю синтаксис такой - `StartCoroutine(_coroutine());`

Comment: Так попробовали?

Comment: @Арман пробовал, синтаксис там и другой может быть: `StartCoroutine(_coroutine(/*param1, param2*/));`, `StartCoroutine("_coroutine");`.

Comment: @Methorn в предложенной Вами ситуации так наверное и есть, в моей ситуации UI кнопки, при касании кнопки, вызывается стоп

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте StartCoroutine(BlinkindRun(сюда передавайте необходимые параметры));, так как 
эта перегрузка выполняет метод по-другому. Также немного смущает while (true). 
Попробуйте вместо true написать какую-нибудь переменную bool, а затем, когда нужно остановить корутин, ставить этой переменной значение false

Answer (score 0):

## Решение

Попробуйте вот так:

```cs
private IEnumerator _coroutine()
{
    //тут то что должен выполняться в короутине
}
```

Запускать и остановить можете так:

```
StartCoroutine(_coroutine());
StopCoroutine(_coroutine());
```

## Другой метод

Если хотите просто делать мигание кнопки можете вот так:

```cs
public Button JustAButton;

private void Update()
{
    float time = 1.0f
    float progress = Mathf.PingPong(0, time) * Time.deltaTime;
    if(progress == 0)
    {
        JustAButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.White;
    }
    else if(progress == 1)
    {
        JustAButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: ох, голова заболела, не представляю как привязать "другой" метод, `Update` я не трогаю вообще. Наверно все в дело в `while(true)`.

Comment: Что вам не понятно? Мой предложенный вариант или решение к вопросу?

Comment: как применить Ваше решение, т.е. исходя из моего кода, когда я касаюсь UI кнопки вызывается `stopFI`, функцию `Update` я не использую, поэтому `Time.deltaTime` не будет считать. Ваше решение имеет место быть, но чтобы у меня ничего не переписывать нужно контролировать цикл `while`